# Can I set a hard limit on my AWS spend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

Is there a way I can set a limit on my AWS spend? I've tried AWS Budgets and also CloudWatch. but they seem to support only notifications- unless I'm missing something.

Comment: While you can't set a spending limit,  you can set up an alert when your AWS spending reaches a certain threshold.

Comment: If you don't want an alert, what exactly do you want when the spending reaches the limit?

Comment: "what exactly do you want", well, for a sandbox/playground account, I want it to shut down all resources that cost money.

Answer (score 9):

No it is not possible.

You can set only the notifications if forecasting cost exceeds the threshold through AWS budgets / CloudWatch.